# Hide filter element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble hiding relevant data with JS.

In my code I have data-type = "power" and data-type = "grill" which are added to the products.

I want the script to check sort filters and hide those that are not present on the page.

Unfortunately, when I have two cases, it doesn't work as it should.

Grill filters do not appear even though they should.

```js
$('.stat').on('click', function() {
  var $stats = $('.stat:checked');
  var $items = $('.list .product');

  $items.show();
  if ($stats.length == 0)
    return;

  var $vstats = $.map($stats, function(o) {
    return $(o).data('id');
  });

  $stats.each(function() {
    var $stat = $(this);
    $items.filter(function() {

      var $currentitem = $(this).data($stat.data('type'));

      if ($currentitem.toString().indexOf(",") > -1) {
        var $item = $currentitem.split(",");
        var hit = 0;
        $item.forEach(function(m) {
          if ($vstats.indexOf(m) > -1) {
            hit++;
          }
        });

        if (hit > 0) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }

      } else {
        if ($vstats.indexOf($currentitem) > -1) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }

    }).hide();
  })
});


var powers = $('[data-power]').map(function() {
  return this.dataset.power;
}).get();
var grills = $('[data-grill]').map(function() {
  return this.dataset.grill;
}).get();

$('[data-id]').filter(function() {
  return !powers.includes(this.dataset.id)
  return !grills.includes(this.dataset.id)
}).closest("label").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="power">
  <h2>power</h2>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input data-id="750" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">750
    </label>
    <label>
      <input data-id="800" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">800
    </label>
    <label>
      <input data-id="1200" data-type="power" class="stat power" type="checkbox">1200
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grill">
  <h2>grill</h2>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input data-id="yes" data-type="grill" class="stat grill" type="checkbox">yes
    </label>
    <label>
      <input data-id="no" data-type="grill" class="stat grill" type="checkbox">no
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list">


  <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 product" data-power="750" data-grill="yes">
    <a href="/href/freh">
      <div class="product-page__container product-container text-center">
        <div class="product-page__name">
          <h2><span class="d-block">Product Name</span> Product 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 product" data-power="800" data-grill="yes">
    <a href="/href/freh">
      <div class="product-page__container product-container text-center">
        <div class="product-page__name">
          <h2><span class="d-block">Product Name 2</span> Product 2</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your filter function. You are returning two values but it stops on first return.

Change

`return !powers.includes(this.dataset.id)` and `return !grills.includes(this.dataset.id)`

to

`return !powers.includes(this.dataset.id) && !grills.includes(this.dataset.id)`;

I hope this will solve you problem.